# Submitting a video with Thumbnail to Facebook Graph API for Instagram

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I have this endpoint that is currently working flawlessly for both photos and videos.

```
let mediaContainerUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/${igUserId}/media`;
```

As per my users demand I also want to add the ability to upload a video thumbnail for videos uploaded to instagram.

will `thumbnail_url` work as the video thumbnail parameter?

Here is what I tried:

```
let videoContainerParams = new URLSearchParams();
videoContainerParams .append('media_type', 'VIDEO');
videoContainerParams .append('video_url', videoUrl);
videoContainerParams .append('thumbnail_url', instagramVideoThumbnail); //Will this work for the video thumbnail?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the easiest to just try it?

Comment: @WizKid I have tried setting `thumbnail_url` in the request but the video thumbnail is not reflecting on Instagram. Is there another way to set it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thumbnail URL [is not supported by the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media), you can only use thumbnail offset to choose which frame of the video will be used as thumbnail.

> **thumb_offset**
>
> Location, in milliseconds, of the video frame to be used as the video's cover thumbnail image. Default value is 0, which is the first frame of the video.